# How can I scale and animate an element from one corner to another without it rotating?

Tags: css, css-animations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8r7.png)I'm trying to animate and scale an element from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner of my webpage using CSS keyframes; I kind of got it working, but it rotates at some point and I don't want the rotation. Here is my code:

```css
.element {
    animation-name: heading;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    transform: translateX() scale(2,2);
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-direction: normal;
} 
@keyframes heading {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(700px) scale(-4,4);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px) scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="home"> 
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="./"><img src="assets/img/Logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is the real code it is just a logo that need to animate.

Comment: But there is nothing with class="element" in your code, and it doesn't animate.

Comment: By the way, are you talking about the flipping around that happens when scaling from a negative to a positive size?

Comment: Yes it is working good what i dont like is the flipping. Here is the demo:  https://codepen.io/moalanteh/pen/rYYvRO

Comment: Then what _DO_ you expect to happen when the element grows fro a negative to a positive width? At one time during the animation, it has got a width of zero!